# Facebook oauth authentication in java only returns username and id

Tags: java, facebook, oauth

I am trying to fetch user details and oauth authenticate user through facebook api's and java and able to authenticate and redirect to my home page but the facebook api's are not returning details like **email , birthday, friend list** but only returns **username and id** and the rest details as null. I have registered my App on facebook and still why i am not able to fetch other details like **birthday , email , friendlist,profile picture** etc.

Below is the code :

This is Main Menu Class :

```
 public class MainMenu extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String code="";

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {      


         String clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
         String clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        //public static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8080/Facebook_Login/fbhome";

        Client client = new Client(clientId, clientSecret);
        FacebookFactory facebookFactory = new FacebookFactory(client);
        String redirectURL = facebookFactory.getRedirectURL("http://localhost:8080/Facebook_Login/fbhome", Display.POPUP, Permission.EMAIL, Permission.OFFLINE_ACCESS);
        String code = req.getParameter("code");
        OAuthAccessToken accessToken1;
        try {
            accessToken1 = facebookFactory.getOAuthAccessToken(code, "http://localhost:8080/Facebook_Login/fbhome");

        Facebook facebook = facebookFactory.getInstance(accessToken1);
        User fbUser = facebook.getCurrentUser();



        System.out.println("fbUser"+"====="+fbUser.getName());

        ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
        res.reset();
        out.println("<h1>Facebook Login using Java</h1>");
        out.println("<h2>Application Main Menu</h2>");
        out.println("<div>Welcome "+fbUser.getName());
        out.println("<div>Your Religion: "+fbUser.getReligion());
        out.println("<div>Your Birthday: "+fbUser.getBirthday());

        out.println("<div>Your Gender: "+fbUser.getGender());
        out.println("<div>Your Locale: "+fbUser.getLocale());

        out.println("<div>Your ID: "+fbUser.getWork());
        out.println("<div>Logout: "+"<a href='https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next="+"http://localhost:8080/Facebook_Login/fbhome&access_token="+accessToken1+"'>Logout"+"</>");

        //out.println("<div>Your Education: "+fbUser.home(facebook));
        Map<String, String> fbProfile = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(fbUser);
        try {
            fbProfile.put("id", json.getString("id"));
            System.out.println("fbProfile"+fbProfile);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






        } catch (FacebookException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();


        }



        /*out.println("<div>You are "+fbProfileData.get("gender"));
        out.flush();*/

    }

}
```

and I am using face4j-1.5.11.jar

Below is the html

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Java Facebook Login</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div
        >
        <a href="<%=fbConnection.getFBAuthUrl()%>"> <img
            style="margin-top: 138px;" src="./img/facebookloginbutton.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you are doing something wrong but because you haven't told us what you do we can not help you

Comment: Now you can have  look .. of the code ..pls suggest !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the graph API doesn't return all fields, so I think the library you are using is not allowing you to request more.

You can test using the console https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

```
$ fbapi '/v2.8/me'
{
  "name": "Yuri Schimke",
  "id": "zzzzzz"
}

$ fbapi '/v2.8/me?fields=name,email,birthday,picture&debug=all'
{
  "name": "Yuri Schimke",
  "email": "www@xxxx.zz",
  "birthday": "xx/xx/xxxx",
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/xxxx.jpg"
    }
  },
  "id": "xxxx",
  "__debug__": {}
}
```